# Multiple name attributes in Dropzone

Tags: laravel, dropzone.js

Good day,

I am trying to implement Dropzone in a Laravel project. Could someone please advise on how I could add multiple name attributes to the Dropzone script, in order to upload the images in different locations and store the image names in the database? Please find the code below. Assistance would be appreciated.

View file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       Dropzone.options.dropzone =
       {
           maxFilesize: 10,
           renameFile: function (file) {
               var dt = new Date();
               var time = dt.getTime();
               return time + file.name;
           },
           acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
           addRemoveLinks: true,
           timeout: 60000,
           success: function (file, response) {
               console.log(response);
           },
           error: function (file, response) {
               return false;
           }
       };
   </script>
```

Controller:

```
 public function store(Request $request)
   {

// Upload image 1
       $image1 = $request->file('file1');
       $avatarName = $image1->getClientOriginalName();

       $image1->move(storage_path('app/public/images/image1'),$avatarName);
       $imageUpload = new Image();
       $imageUpload->filename = $avatarName;
       $imageUpload->save();
       return response()->json(['success'=>$avatarName]);

// Upload image 2
       $image2 = $request->file('file2');
       $avatarName = $image2->getClientOriginalName();

       $image2->move(storage_path('app/public/images/image2'),$avatarName);
       $imageUpload = new Image();
       $imageUpload->filename = $avatarName;
       $imageUpload->save();
       return response()->json(['success'=>$avatarName]);

//Save image names in the database   
       $user = Auth::user();
       $property = new Property;

       $property->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
       $property->image1 = $image1;
       $property->image2 = $image2;

       $user->save();
       $property->save();
       return redirect('/users/listings')->with('success', 'Listing has been created.');   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each drop zone has just 1 name which obtains from the input file tag, So you need 2 drop zones to do that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to provide an option for about 15 images that users can upload for each post. Could you please on whether you know of any alternative / workaround in order to use one Dropzone for all the images?

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I think I will go with multiple dropzones for now and just resize the dropzone containers. The multiple dropzones might also work well when a user would like to edit or replace a specific image at a later stage.

Comment: There are not much options compare to dropzone which is free. But there is one option which is not that much pretty but can work well too. check it out https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-upload-with-preview
and if you want to use any thing fancy with lots of cool features use this one but you have to pay for the featured version: https://innostudio.de/fileuploader/